# Detect and avoid 100% CPU usage due to incorrect join query

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, ado.net

We have a `C#` application in which the end user can connect to their database server and run a query to fetch the data. We execute the query using `ADO.NET` in the codebase and process the data according to our application.

Sometimes, the end user will mistakenly enter an incorrect join query or join relationship, which is syntactically correct but not the intended query. This incorrect join or bad query causes the database server to use a larger or 100% of its CPU, causing an issue. Are there any options at the code or database level to validate the query to find irrelevant join conditions or relationships and to avoid such scenarios?

> The end-user can manually track the CPU usage, but this is not a viable option. We are looking for options to avoid this automatically, either at the code level or the database level.

Comment: Databases usually have something like explain that shows your query complexity. Maybe this can help? Another option we do: Never let users query your live database servers. Just "backup/slave" servers.

Comment: If you have only a limited number of database vendors, you can query the database for it's usage resources (like SSMS can do). E.g. [for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-issues#step-2-identify-queries-contributing-to-cpu-usage)

Comment: A 100% CPU usage is not by definition wrong or a problem. A query plan that will scan millions or even billions of rows, that should return a flag "Are you sure?" to the end user.

Comment: A user with direct SQL access to the dbms can always ask performance demanding queries. (Recursive cte's etc.)

Comment: How do you anticipate detecting a bad query described from a perfectly valid (correct) query that needs those resources?

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent that by configuring PostgreSQL as follows:

- set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0`, so that a single SQL statement can never use more than a single CPU core
- set `statement_timeout` to a reasonably low value, so that statements that take too long are automatically canceled